# Do I need to drop table variables declared in stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

In a stored procedure if I

```
DECLARE @tmpClientTable TABLE
```

Would I need to drop it again? Or would it just get overwritten next time stored proc runs.

What would happen if someone else ran the stored proc too....would that be a separate table?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to (and actually can't) explicitly drop it.

The creation and dropping of table variables is handled for you automatically.

In a stored procedure the table variables can be cached rather than repeatedly being dropped and created. See [Temporary Table Caching Explained](http://web.archive.org/web/20180422150925/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/08/17/temporary-object-caching-explained.aspx) for more about this.

A concurrent user would get a separate execution context and separate instance of the table variable.

Comment: The key thing from that link is "_SQL Server 2005 onward caches temporary tables **and table variables**_", since these are two quite different things. I point this out because OP made the same mistake and so readers can be sure the link is indeed relevant.

Answer (score 2):

It's a table variable. It can't / doesn't need to be dropped.

It has local scope in the stored procedure, meaning any concurrent connections running the same `PROC` will be isolated from eachother.

Answer (score 2):

Table variables drop immediately after execution.

For example:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE( 
name varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
location varchar(30) NOT NULL 
);

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES( 'John', 'Neveda')

SELECT * FROM @Table
go
```

After Executing the above, try this in the same session:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE( 
name varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
location varchar(30) NOT NULL ,
locationB varchar(30) NOT NULL 
);

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES( 'John', 'Neveda', 'LasVegas')

SELECT * FROM @Table
```

Where as Temp Tables will not be dropped until the session is closed.
[LocalTempTables Vs GlobalTempTables](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42553/Quick-Overview-Temporary-Tables-in-SQL-Server-2005)

Comment: This only works if you are running the above query in separate chunks.  If you run it all at once, you get an error because the table already exists.

Comment: @datagod - Good point! You can run it all at once if you replace `After Executing this try this in the same session.` with a `GO`

Answer (score 0):

this is (one version of) the #TEMP table syntax.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempCustomer') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #TempCustomer
end


CREATE TABLE #TempCustomer
( 
  [CustomerID] nchar(5)
, [CompanyName] nvarchar(40)
)


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempCustomer') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #TempCustomer
end
```

You cannot drop a @variable table.